# How can I merge all the CSS files in my Wordpress website into one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I found out that I have 19(!!!!!!) different CSS files in my Wordpress directory.
I am not sure if I can just simply move all the selectors from all the different files into one general file?

If not, which actions do I need to take in order to do this?
It slows down the whole website and I'm not sure how to approach this.

Thanks in advance!

p.s I have the same issue with Javascript files, does it take the same approach?

Comment: Most cache plugins, such as WP Fastest Cache https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/, does this in order to speed up the loading. They simply combine both css and/or js files to reduce the number of requests.

Comment: Are these style sheets related to different plugins or are they all your own 'extras'?

Comment: @AHaworth I have not created any CSS files of my own ( only except the custom CSS inside the WP dashboard under the 'customize' tab - but it only contains 5 lines of code )

Answer (score -1):

Try using  Autoptimize WordPress plugin [here's the link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) or W3 Total Cache WordPress plugin [here's the link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/). They are easily available to download.

**Note:** With W3 Total cache enable minify option.

They both support combining and minifying all enqueued JavaScripts (JS) and Stylesheet (CSS).

Comment: Thanks! I have installed the Autoptimize plugin which drastically improved the JS files ( reduced from 9 to 2 ), but the CSS has been reduced from 14 to 6 and I can't seem to be able to merge the rest?